# Android maps medir distancias y al estar cerca que haga un cambio

Tags: android-studio

Estoy haciendo una juego en android con maps. Tengo 3 puntos clave que son a los que hay que llegar, cada punto tiene su marker y sus coordenadas, esto funciona bien, ahora lo que no consigo es que cuando yo esté a unos metros de distancia de uno de los marker me pare la música de fondo que tengo y se inicie otra, quien dice música dice otra cosa.

Os pongo como tengo un marker:

```
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(42.237439, -8.714226);
    int radius = 10;

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .radius(radius)
            .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#0D47A1"))
            .strokeWidth(4)
            .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#AF4046FF"));
    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Mision 1.")
            .snippet("Fundador: user")        
       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sound1)));
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    Location location1p = new Location("mision1");
    location1p.setLatitude(42.237439);
    location1p.setLongitude(-8.714226);
    distancia1 = locationGPS.distanceTo(location1p);
    lblPista.setText("Mts a mision1: "+distancia1);
```

distancia1 está declarado como float en la main

Como veis tengo declarado el marker con su circulo y el distanceTo() que sería para determinar desde mi posicion actual cuanto quedaría para llegar hasta ese punto en metros supongo.
Si yo hago un método con un if diciéndole "si distancia1 es menor o igual a 10 para la música de fondo y reproduce esta":

```
private void localizacionPistas() {

    if(distancia1 <= 10){
        musicafondo.stop();
        guerra.start();
    }       
}
```

Que es lo que está mal para que no funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, ya descubrí el problema. No se puede utilizar Location solo, hay que usar el LocationListener. Lo que hice fue usar el LocationListener de los métodos que me estaban devolviendo mi posicion en el mapa vía GPS:

Este es un método que le indico a 20metros de distancia desde el marker, cambia el sonido de la app y si esta a mas de 10metros que se pare ese sonido:

```
private void distancia_a_puntoA(Location localitation) {
    distancia1 = localitation.distanceTo(location1);
    lblPanda.setText(("Mts a Punto A: " + distancia1));
    if (localitation.distanceTo(locationa) <= metroscerca) {
        sound1.start();
    } else if (localitation.distanceTo(locationa) > metroslejos) {
        sound1.stop();
    }
}
```

//Aquí sería donde tenemos que añadir el método para que nos funcione correctamente las distancias

```
LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        actualizarUbicacion(location);

        distancia_a_puntoA(location); //este es el método de arriba


        Log.i(TAG, "Lat " + location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
        lblLatitud.setText(("Lat: " +   location.getLatitude()));
        lblLongitud.setText(("Long: " + location.getLongitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled()");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled()");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled()");

    }
};
```